# How do i add separate elements to a list in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, if-statement, dom

Im trying to make an option, for the user to create a list of owned records. However i ran into the following problem:

1. When the user tries to create a list with no name, an empty/invisible element is added to the list. I want the code, to ask the user to enter a name if he leaves the prompt blank.
2. When elements are added, i want them to be separate and different elements. Now they are shown and displayed as one.

I hope some of you guys can help me overcome this problem. Please ask if anything seems unclear.

My present code is presented below:

```js
function myFunction1() {
  var txt;
  var person = prompt("Please enter the name of your record list:");
  if (person == null || person == "") {
    txt = "";
  } else {
    txt = person + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("myRecords").innerHTML += txt;
}
```

```html
<a id="myRecords"></a>
<a id="create" onclick="myFunction1()">Create RecordList</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something like an (un)ordered list (`<ol>`, `<ul>`) and then append list item (`<li>`) containing the name in an `<a>` tag if need be. If you want to append an empty item when a name isn't entered, you don't have to use an if statement.

```js
const getRecordList = () => document.getElementById('recordList');
const getCreateButton = () => document.getElementById('create');

function promptInput(value = '') {
  const message = 'Please enter the name of your record list:';
  let name = '';
  while (name === '') {
    name = prompt(message, value);
  }
  return name;
}

function createListItem(name) {
  const listItem = document.createElement('li');
  listItem.innerHTML = `<a onclick="updateRecord(this)">${name}</a>`;
  return listItem;
}

function createRecord() {
  const name = promptInput();
  if (!name) return;
  getRecordList().appendChild(createListItem(name || ''));
}

function updateRecord(li) {
  li.innerHTML = promptInput(li.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<h2>Record List</h2>
<ol id="recordList"></ol><hr>
<button id="create" onclick="createRecord()">Create</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! If possible i want to keep the element as an <a>. This does not seem to be possible with this solution. Is there anything im missing?

Comment: Sure, I created a new function that creates the list item with an `<a>` tag wrapping the name.

Answer (score 1):

When using `prompt`, it's best to use a `while` loop to make sure that input is entered. This will continue cycling the message until the user enters sufficient information. When a user hits `cancel` a null value is returned. Within the `while` loop we check if person is null, and if that is the case we immediately return.

To add separate elements you can use `document.createElement` and then append that element to your selected parent through the use of the `appendChild` method.

In the below code I took the liberty of converting your myRecords div into a `ul` or unordered list tag. When names are entered they are added as `li` ( list item ) children to this tag.

```js
function myFunction1() {
  var person, ul = document.getElementById("myRecords"), li = document.createElement("li");
  while (!person) {
    person = prompt("Please enter the name of your record list:");
    if (person == null) return;
  }
  li.textContent = person;
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
myFunction1();
myFunction1();
```

```html
<ul id="myRecords"></ul>
```

If you don't want to use a list, you can simply update the markup and change what you are appending. In the below `myRecords` is an `a` tag. We append a `div` with the appropriate text to this anchor tag as we did in the above.

```js
function myFunction1() {
  var person, a = document.getElementById("myRecords"), div = document.createElement("div");
  while (!person) {
    person = prompt("Please enter the name of your record list:");
    if (person == null) return;
  }
  div.textContent = person;
  a.appendChild(div);
}
myFunction1();
```

```html
<a id="myRecords" href="#"></a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip - this worked for me. If possible, i preffer to have the element with id="myRecords" as a <a>. If i change the element back to an <a> this solution dont seem to work though.

Comment: @tobiasmadsen17 Well, it won't work with `li` child elements if you change the `ul` to an `a`, as the only element that can have `li` children is `ul/ol`. Then do `li = document.createElement("div")` and it will work (and you might want to change the _li_ var name to _div_).

Answer (score 0):

you need to change your JS to the following:

```js
function myFunction1() {
  var txt;
  var person = prompt("Please enter the name of your record list:");
  if (person == "") {
      alert('Please enter a name');
      return;
  } else if(person == null){
      return;
  } else {
      txt =  person;
  }
  var span = document.createElement('span');
  span.setAttribute('class', 'myElement');
  span.innerHTML = txt;
  
  document.getElementById("myRecords").appendChild(span);
}
```

```html
<a id="myRecords"></a>
<a id="create" onclick="myFunction1()">Create RecordList</a>
```

With createElement a new element is created, to add a class you can use setAttribute and then you append it as a child to your myRecords element via appendChild.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly what you're trying to accomplish, this is the solution I came up with for you:

```js
function myFunction(prompt_text) {
  var txt;
  var list;
  var person;
  if (prompt_text != '' && prompt_text != undefined) {
    person = prompt(prompt_text);
  } else {
    person = prompt("Please enter the name of your record list:");
  }
  if (person == null || person == "") {
    txt = "";
  } else {
    txt = '<li>' + person + "</li>";
  }
  if (txt != '') {
    document.getElementById("myRecords").innerHTML += txt;
  } else if(person != null){
    myFunction("Names cannot be blank, please enter the name of your record list:");
  } else {
    return;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul id="myRecords"></ul>
<a id="create" onclick="myFunction()">Create RecordList</a>
```

I've modified the container that you're putting the data into to be an unordered list `<ul></ul>` to better facilitate having multiple entries in it, and auto-appended the `<li></li>` DOM so that the list does all of the work for you.

I've also changed the function to accept `prompt_text` as a parameter, so you can recursively call the function if they don't enter text.

**EDIT:** updated the code to understand the `null` returned when a user clicks the cancel button, which removes the error that was created by the code I originally posted.

The final change is the recursive function call I mentioned above. If the `txt` variable is empty, the function calls itself with new `prompt_text` allowing you to let the user know WHY they didn't do it right, as well as giving them another opportunity to correct that.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction1() {
  let person = prompt("Please enter the name of your record list:");
  if (person) {
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerText=person;
    document.getElementById("myRecords").appendChild(div);
  }else{
    alert('Please enter a name');
  }
}
```

```html
<a id="myRecords"></a>
<a id="create" onclick="myFunction1()">Create RecordList</a>
```

You can `createElement` and `appendChild` to add desired elements.

Comment: Thank you! This solution also worked. The problem was about about the creation of an element, and appendChild to that. Thanks for the tip :-)